# Unknown 'VisualforceArrayList.Receiver_of_commodity__r' property help

Tags: apex

I'm getting this error: Unknown 'VisualforceArrayList.Recibidor_de_mercaderia__r' property
on vfp.
I want to show the contents of this variable inside the vfp, and i am using a custom controller.  I appreciate any help

Controller:

````
       public List <Opportunity> getEndereco(){
           system.debug('idOpp= '+idOpp);
            if(enderecoConta == null) {
                enderecoConta = [SELECT Id, Recibidor_de_mercaderia__r.CEP__c 
                    FROM Opportunity 
                    WHERE Id =: idOpp
                    LIMIT 1];
            }
            return enderecoConta;
             }
      }

VFP:
          </tr>
             <tr><th id="title1">Local da Entrega:</th>
             <td><apex:outputField value="{!Endereco.Recibidor_de_mercaderia__r.Rua__c}" /></td></tr>   
                         ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Endereco` is a `List<Opportunity>`, so you have to either access a specific element, or iterate over the values. What I think you may have meant to write is:

```
<td><apex:outputField value="{!Endereco[0].Recibidor_de_mercaderia__r.Rua__c}" /></td>
```

Note that if there are no results, this will result in an error. You may want to change the variable to just an Opportunity, so you can return an empty Opportunity if no results are found:

```
public Opportunity getEndereco(){
   system.debug('idOpp= '+idOpp);
    if(enderecoConta == null) {
        enderecoConta = [SELECT Id, Recibidor_de_mercaderia__r.CEP__c, Recibidor_de_mercaderia__r.Rua__c, 
                        Recibidor_de_mercaderia__r.Municipio__r.Name, Recibidor_de_mercaderia__r.Bairro__c, 
                        Recibidor_de_mercaderia__r.Estado__c, Recibidor_de_mercaderia__r.Numero__c, owner.lastname,
                        owner.Email,owner.CPF__c 
            FROM Opportunity 
            WHERE Id =: idOpp
            LIMIT 1];
    }
    return enderecoConta.isEmpty() ? new Opportunity(): enderecoConta[0];

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: @Carolyne Glad to be of service!